# Removing parts of Joomla CMS

Tags: php, web-applications, joomla, joomla2.5

### Background

I have been developing a web application. I have been using Joomla platform and CMS as the base from my application. My application relies heavily on the joomla platform, but uses very few features of the CMS (I have to login users etc so I use the _users component of the CMS).

### Question

What is the best way to start removing some of the excess CMS that I don't need? For example when I being building my production site, I will want to avoid creating a load of joomla component database tables etc. I have read that an application can be build from the ground up  using just the joomla platform, but i still want to include the _users component and would also like to avoid having to start coding all the session handling aspects.

I guess I need to continue to have the basic CMS application, but with a really stripped down list of core components and no administrator backend.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall core extensions and modules using the extension manager.  At that point if you want you could rebuild the joomla.sql file with just the tables you need (I recommend always doing this by exporting an actual database you have gone through this procedure with, don't try to do it by hand) and zip up the whole thing as an installable package.

In terms of back end in principle they are totally independent but there are some models and maybe some helpers called from the backend by the front end, so you will want to look at what you have left when you are done and then think about it.  In particular the articles model is one you will want to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only aspect that I really need to use is user management. Im confused by the split between platform and CMS. Platform has the JUser class. Does that mean that user management is part of platform? If it is I will get rid of all of CMS and create my own application from scratch, as I only need user management.

Comment: You can create your own user management from the platform using JUser and JTableUser and JCrypt for the passwords and so on.  It's not as simple as it should be yet which in my opinion is one reason we don't see more platform applications, however it definitely can be done.  CRMery the CRM that is a platform application has authentication and user management if you want to look at their code.

Comment: Thanks Elin - apart from looking at CRMery and the documentation, are their any tutorials you could point me to?

Comment: Not really unfortunately especially for the user management. In terms of the platform in general http://joomla.github.com/joomla-platform/